# I want to wrap the functions I've made, in a single function so it is a single piece of code. How do I do that?

Tags: python, function

These are my 3 functions.

```
    def fetch_data(url_link):
    url=url_link
    xml_data = requests.get(url).content
    fetch_data.soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_data, "xml")
```

```
def meta_data(soup):
    # Name of filing company
    company = soup.find('filingManager').find('name').string
            # Company identifier: Central Index Key
    CIK = soup.find('cik').string
            # Form type: 13F-HR
    formtype = soup.find('submissionType').string
            # 13F-HR file number
    fileNumber = soup.find('form13FFileNumber').string
            # Reporting date (e.g. 03-31-2020)
    period_of_report_date = datetime.strptime(soup.find('periodOfReport').string, '%m-%d-%Y').date()
            # Filing date (up to 45 days after reporting date)
    filing_date = datetime.strptime(soup.find('signatureDate').string, '%m-%d-%Y').date()
    info_dict={"filingManager":company,"cik":CIK,"TYPE":formtype,"form13FFileNumber":fileNumber,
               "periodOfReport":period_of_report_date,'signatureDate':filing_date}
    meta_data.info_data=pd.DataFrame((info_dict),index=[0])
```

```
def concate(info_data,data):
    newdf = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(info_data.values,266,axis=0))
    newdf.columns = info_data.columns
    concate.df=pd.concat([newdf,data],axis=1)
```

Now I want to enclose these 3 functions into a single function such that I can call them using a single function. Something like

```
def xml2df(url_link):
   def function 1:
   call function 1
   def function 2:
   call function 2
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: You already know how to do this, and in fact you have already done it in your code. Hint: when you wrote `def meta_data(soup):`, how did you (and I am telling you, you did) "enclose" all the calls to `soup.find` etc. in a single function?

Comment: Unless the question is "how do I get a function to return data to use somewhere else"; in which case, I carefully chose the word `return` for that sentence, and you should check a Python tutorial or a search engine to understand. Stack Overflow is not a place to learn the fundamentals of the language and it does not replace tutorials or documentation.

Comment: Thanks! I got what you're trying to portray.